# Other options to draw line chart

Tags: linux

Is there any tool/library which allows me to draw line chart via command line and save the result to an image?

Some thing like this which let me use my own data to generate a line chart? But this one is web based.
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

I am looking for some thing I can run via command line so that it can script that.

I am running on Ubuntu/cygwin.

Thank you.

Comment: [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is quite good for charting/plotting data etc. It can be run on it's own from a gnuplot script, or inside a perl or shell script for a bit more power. Otherwise, there's the all powerful python option with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) and [numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/). Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

There is also rrdtool.

http://aplawrence.com/Girish/gv-rrdtool.html

This site contains some examples of how to interface with rrdtool from shell.  This is what mrtg and ganglia have used for years to generate traffic flow graphing.

I prefer gnuplot myself.  But, rrdtool is a powerful tool for time series charting.